# T-SQL: alter sequence number current_value without changing start_value

Tags: sql-server, sequence

I know how to alter a sequence number via the alter statement. :

```
ALTER SEQUENCE dbo.seq_SomeSequnce 
    RESTART WITH @someRandomNumber
```

The above will reset the `current_value` and `start_value` with the `sys.sequence` table of the database. I need to modify only the current value of the sequence without modifying the `start_value`.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this? Just curious. Cause, I suppose you could just create a NEW sequence and start using that, but i'm unsure of why you are worried about the start_value being reset.

Comment: Have a problem where an error in a process is using up sequence  numbers and then throwing an exception.  The solution was to alter the sequence number after such an error, but this causes issues with other processes.

Comment: By default sequences aren’t unique. To keep that from happening you’d need to roll back the transaction on error to prevent them from being consumed. I assume this isn’t happening, based on your info. Any chance we can change that?

Comment: Unfortunately, the scenario does not allow for rollback.  It is not a sql statement or stored procedure.

Comment: Let me rephrase that, it is not a sql statement that can be wrapped in a transaction.

Comment: Why not? There is an implicit transaction already there :). Maybe someone else has a better solution but altering the sequence every time seems like a bad idea

Comment: It is a generated sql bulk insert statement via ssis.